# How do I link this slider value with this <p> tag?

Tags: javascript, html

Everything in this code functions how I want it to except I don't know how to make whatever number is on the slider be applied to the `number` variable.  Any help you can give I would appreciate so much!

```js
var range = document.querySelector('.inputRange');
var field = document.getElementById('num1');

range.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
    field.value = e.target.value;
});

field.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
    range.value = e.target.value;
});



var number = 2000;
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = number.toLocaleString('en');

var number2 = number;

if (number2 >= 10000) {
    number2 = Math.round(+number + 10);
}
else if (number2 >= 5000) {
    number2 = Math.round(+number + 5);
}
else {
    number2 = Math.round(+number + 1);
}

document.getElementById("id2").innerHTML = number2.toLocaleString('en');
```

```html
<input class="inputRange" type="range" min="1000" max="50000" value="1000" step="1000" id="slider"/>
<input class="inputNumber" id="num1" min="0" max="100" type="number" value="1000" />

<p> <span id="id"></span></p>
<p>$<span id="id2"></span></p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rY3Tj/292/  This should help!

Comment: You have two p tags, which p tag you referring to?

Comment: Sorry.  In my Javascript I have a variable "var number = 2000;" and by the end it outputs to the first <p> tag with the id="id".  I can't seem to figure out how to get the value from the slider to be used as the value for var number.  2000 is just placeholder for now.  Thank you for taking time time to help out!

Comment: Please test out my snippet, if it was not what you've meant, please explain it to me.

Comment: I am sorry if I didn't explain it very well, I am new to programming.  What you made is almost perfect!  Although what I am looking to change is just the "var number = 2000;" into "var number = slider/numberValue;" so that whatever is in either the slider or the number beside it will be equal to "var number" so I can change that number later on with "var number2".  Thank you for helping, Wils!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    var range = document.querySelector('.inputRange');
    var field = document.getElementById('num1');
    
    var number2 = 2001;
    
    var numberHtml = document.getElementById("id");    
    var number2Html = document.getElementById("id");
            
    range.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
        field.value = e.target.value;
        SetNumberValues(field.value);
    });    
    
    field.addEventListener('input', function (e) {     
        field.value = e.target.value;
        SetNumberValues(field.value);
    });
    
    function SetNumberValues(fieldValue)
    {
    
     numberHtml.innerHTML = fieldValue.toLocaleString('en');        
    
    if (fieldValue >= 10000) {
        number2 = Math.round(+fieldValue + 10);
    }
    else if (fieldValue >= 5000) {
        number2 = Math.round(+fieldValue + 5);
    }
    else {
        number2 = Math.round(+fieldValue + 1);
    }
    
    document.getElementById("id2").innerHTML = number2.toLocaleString('en');
    }
```

```html
    <input class="inputRange" type="range" min="1000" max="50000" value="1000" step="1000" id="slider"/>
    <input class="inputNumber" id="num1" min="1000" max="50000" step="1000" type="number" value="1000" />
    
    <p> <span id="id">2000</span></p>
    <p>$<span id="id2">2001</span></p>
```

Comment: Your range can dip to 1000, but I initially set it as 2000/2001.

Comment: This is perfect!  Although, I was testing and found that changing the number beside the slider has no effect on the number like the slider has.  Is there any way I can fix that?  Thank you so much for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code: http://jsfiddle.net/e0s8z4hm/

Basically in `range.addEventListener` you were not updating value in #id2.

Current :

```
range.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
    field.value = e.target.value;
});
```

Do it :

```
range.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  field.value = e.target.value;
```

> $('#id2').html(e.target.value); // add this line

```
});
```